# How do you associate one model with another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-design

I have a model called Topic and another called Product.

Here's how the Topic model looks,

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
end
```

Topic has columns "title" and "body".

And here's Product,

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :topics
end
```

Product has columns "name" and "desc". Name is unique.

When I create a new Topic, I want the title of Topic to be stored in Name of Product, only if Name doesn't exist yet. If it does, it should not make any change.

But how do I do this?

UPDATE:

User comes to /topics page, enters Title and Body.

What the Topics_controller should do,
1. Read the Title that has been given by the user.
2. Check if that Title already exists in the Products.
3. If it doesn't add it.
4. If it does, don't do anything.

I don't understand how these two models are linked together and how I can access records from the model.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using one of the [callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html), which ActiveRecord provides.

I'm not sure if I understand your requirements perfectly, so maybe you need to alter the following example:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
    before_save :add_product_name

    private

    def add_product_name
        self.product.name ||= self.title if Product.find_by(name: self.title).nil?
    end
end
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I needed!! Unfortunately, when the Product table doesn't have a record whose name matches the title of a record in Topic table, the code breaks. Basically I have to create a record in Product table before I create a record in the Topic table.

Comment: Yep, that might be true. I've changed the condition for the assignment.

Comment: Thank you! And how would I access these topics in the products page? How is the relation between Topic and Product actually made?

Comment: Do you this would be correct? I added this to my Products controller.
@topics = Topic.where(:title => Product.find(params[:id]).title)

Comment: The topic is linked to the product through it's foreign key. I recommend you to read the guides. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

You can write a callback like before_create :add_topic_name

Where that method will find product name of topic and assign it to the title of product.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are a bit unclear here.  Can you specify what your end goal is, from a Behaviour point of view?

If i understand correctly though, why not just overwrite the title method for Topic.  This way you are not duplicating data in the DB.

within your Topic class:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
    def title
       read_attribute(:title) || product.name  # will get title of @topic if not nil, else product name
    end
end
```